# Searching across collections based on different column name

Tags: mongodb, query, string-searching

I have following collections with fields in my mongodb database:

Collection: Category

```
[
    {
        "cat_id": "cat_id_1",
        "cat_name": "education"
    },
    {
        "cat_id": "cat_id_2",
        "cat_name": "Sports"
    }
]
```

Collection: Keywords

```
[
        {
            "key_id": "key_id_1",
            "key_name": "social"
        },
        {
            "key_id": "key_id_2",
            "key_name": "places"
        }
    ]
```

Collection: Artists

```
[
    {
        "art_id": "art_id_1",
        "artist_name": "Brian Adams"
    },
    {
        "art_id": "art_id_1",
        "artist_name": "ACDC"
    }
]
```

Collection: Episodes

```
[
    {
        "ep_id": "ep_id_1",
        "ep_title": "Episode Title 1",
        "categories": ["cat_id_1", "cat_id_2"],
        "keywords": ["key_id_1"], 
        "program_id": "pr_id_1", 
        "artists": ["art_id_1", "art_id_2"]
    }
]
```

Collection: Programs

```
[
    {
        "program_id": "pr_id_1",
        "pr_title": "Program Title 1",
        "categories": ["cat_id_1", "cat_id_2"],
        "keywords": ["key_id_1"], 
        "artists": ["art_id_1", "art_id_2"]
    }
]
```

Now I need to write a query which will list programs based on search string matching Category, Artist, keywords, Episodes Title or Program Title. It would have been easy if it's a single collection by just using `find` and `$regex` and supplying searched string to it. However I failed to apply the same for this condition.